# Duplicate class org.opencv.videoio.Videoio found in modules jetified-opencv-4.3.0-runtime & jetified-opencv-android-gradle-repo-3.3.0-runtime

Tags: android, flutter, opencv, gradle, flutter-dependencies

***[1]*** How to Solve `Duplicate class org.opencv found in modules jetified-opencv-4.3.0-runtime (com.quickbirdstudios:opencv:4.3.0) and jetified-opencv-android-gradle-repo-3.3.0-runtime (com.github.davidmigloz:opencv-android-gradle-repo:3.3.0)`

I'm using `opencv: ^1.0.4` in flutter project

***[2]*** and `Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version` warning.

> flutter build apk

```
 Building with sound null safety 

w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    C:/Users/Administrator/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.30/5fd47535cc85f9e24996f939c2de6583991481b0/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class org.opencv.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-opencv-4.3.0-runtime (com.quickbirdstudios:opencv:4.3.0) and jetified-opencv-android-gradle-repo-3.3.0-runtime (com.github.davidmigloz:opencv-android-gradle-repo:3.3.0)
     Duplicate class org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper found in modules jetified-opencv-4.3.0-runtime (com.quickbirdstudios:opencv:4.3.0) and jetified-opencv-android-gradle-repo-3.3.0-runtime (com.github.davidmigloz:opencv-android-gradle-repo:3.3.0)
     Duplicate class org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback$7 found in modules jetified-opencv-4.3.0-runtime (com.quickbirdstudios:opencv:4.3.0) and jetified-opencv-android-gradle-repo-3.3.0-runtime (com.github.davidmigloz:opencv-android-gradle-repo:3.3.0)
     Duplicate class org.opencv.android.Camera2Renderer found in modules jetified-opencv-4.3.0-runtime (com.quickbirdstudios:opencv:4.3.0) and jetified-opencv-android-gradle-repo-3.3.0-runtime (com.github.davidmigloz:opencv-android-gradle-repo:3.3.0)

     ....

     Duplicate class org.opencv.videoio.Videoio found in modules jetified-opencv-4.3.0-runtime (com.quickbirdstudios:opencv:4.3.0) and jetified-opencv-android-gradle-repo-3.3.0-runtime (com.github.davidmigloz:opencv-android-gradle-repo:3.3.0)

     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           31.6s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Temporarily solved] Opencv_4 does not supporting in Flutter version 3, use alternative dependencies for your code or downgrade the package.